# How many roots are there in an undirected root

Tags: graphs, trees, search-trees, graph-traversal, minimum-spanning-tree

Given an undirected tree with 7 nodes how many roots would this tree have. My intuition tells me that because the tree is undirected it would either be 7 or 0. How would I solve this?

Comment: Usually a tree is "rooted" by picking any vertex to be the root. The root isn't special in terms of properties of the graph

Comment: So in my examples case the undirected tree with 7 nodes can have 7 possible roots because you can choose any node to "start" from?

Comment: Perhaps you should give us the definition of a root of a tree.